# Is there a specific expression to denote territories which were once occupied?

Tags: phrases, vocabulary, history, diction

I have to write a long History essay about territories which were once occupied by one people, but no longer are. Is there a term for that, something like once-[insertpeoplehere]-occupied?

Comment: Are you saying the land is no longer occupied by anyone or that it's no longer occupied by a single people (i.e. a mix of people now live there)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fact that the country was at the time occupied is important, such as wartime, use **then-occupied**

> He was sent to then-occupied France to serve in a battalion of former
>   Soviet prisoners of war...

https://www.history101.com/sides-wwii-yang-kyoungjong/

> By April of 1945, eight months following Nazi massacres in the Saulx
>   valley of then-occupied France,

[https://www.amazon.com/Elbe-Resolution-Lloyd-Holm/dp/0984765433](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0984765433)

If the country was occupied as a colony or dominion, then use **French Senegal**, **British India**, etc., again if the fact of occupation is relevant to the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much!